# unable to delete video from youtube playlist

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, youtube-api

I'm trying to delete a video from a Youtube playlist but the server keeps responding with this:

```
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
    <error>
        <domain>GData</domain>
        <code>ServiceForbiddenException</code>
        <internalReason>User authentication required.</internalReason>
    </error>
</errors>
```

The weird thing is i can delete playlists and and add videos to playlists.
I'm following Google's documentation found here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists#Deleting_a_video_from_a_playlist

I'm using a request shaped like this:

URL

DELETE `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLAYLIST_ID/VIDEO_ID`

DELETE `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLZsHJpFf2dLtEhsYEISc2FR2JWYeIC8KZ/IcxQznDe4u8`

Headers: (i use the exact same headers for ALL requests)

```
Authorization:  Bearer ************************
Content-Type:   application/atom+xml
Host:           gdata.youtube.com
X-GData-Key:    key=***************************
gdata-version:  2
```

Another odd thing is when i type in the request url in the adress it says "Playlist video not found"
I've supplied the Youtube video id. Mebbe it's not that id i need to supply. I tried with playlist index, i.e just a number. No luck. halp!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allow me to answer my own question.

In the documentation linked they've stated that you need a *PLAYLIST_ENTRY_ID* which is not the same *id* that's written in the address on Youtube. This *id* comes from the entries that you request via their feed request. Every entry (every video) has a property named *id* (it's in feed -> entry -> id[text]) which contains something like this:

`tag:youtube.com,2008:playlist:PLZsHJpFf2dLs_n7e69v5SUNQRuZTMnLcM:PLhRVbNPJX-c0PUOsjeulCsgAx-ydeUUdJhpxbacX0VFk`

Which in this case can be understood as

`bla:bla:bla:PLAYLIST_ID:PLAYLIST_ENTRY_ID`

so the id i was looking after was the rest of the string after the last colon.
In Javascript i fetched it like this: (I'm using an xml to json parser, but it's the *.split(":").pop()* that will give you the desired *id*)

```
var deleteId=json.feed.entry[i]["id"]["#text"].split(":").pop();
```

In this case the id resulting id would be: *PLhRVbNPJX-c0PUOsjeulCsgAx-ydeUUdJhpxbacX0VFk*.

So the final request url for the video of ytId IcxQznDe4u8
is not

`https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLZsHJpFf2dLtEhsYEISc2FR2JWYeIC8KZ/IcxQznDe4u8`

but instead

`https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLZsHJpFf2dLtEhsYEISc2FR2JWYeIC8KZ/PLhRVbNPJX-c0PUOsjeulCsgAx-ydeUUdJhpxbacX0VFk`

*flies away*